# For loop iterating through two lists python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have two lists with different values but same length, for example:

```
list1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [6,7,8,9,10,11]
```

and I would like to use a for loop and iterate through both lists simultaneous so that the output would be

```
0,6
1,7
2,8
3,9
4,10
5,11
```

this obviously doesn't work:

```
for val1 in list 1 and val2 ind list2:
   print (val1, val2)
```

and this doesn't generate the output I would like to have:

```
for val1 in list 1: 
   for val2 in list2:
      print (val1, val2)
```

Can you guys please help me?

Comment: Have a look at the [zip function](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i assume that you have the same list length for list1 and list 2

in order to print it you just need to specify the position of the index on list like list[index], this will print the list value.

```
list1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [6,7,8,9,10,11]

for i in range(len(list1)):
    print(f"{list1[i]}, {list2[i]}")
```

Comment: and if the list length were not the same?